# Creating shared_ptr of a class containing a unique_ptr to a forwarded type fails

Tags: c++11

This code

```
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
  class B;
  std::unique_ptr<B> b;
  A();
};

void foo() {
  std::make_shared<A>();
}
```

Fails with:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from aaa.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::default_delete<_Tp>::operator()(_Tp*) const [with _Tp = A::B]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:268:17:   required from ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = A::B; _Dp = std::default_delete<A::B>]’
aaa.cpp:3:7:   required from ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::destroy(_Up*) [with _Up = A; _Tp = A]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:487:4:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::destroy(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type&, _Up*) [with _Up = A; _Tp = A; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<A>]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:535:35:   required from ‘void std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<_Tp, _Alloc, _Lp>::_M_dispose() [with _Tp = A; _Alloc = std::allocator<A>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
aaa.cpp:12:1:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:22: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘A::B’
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

It seems the compiler tries to define a default delete to the `A::B` type that is forward declared.

Can somebody explain why `make_shared` needs to know the default delete? And how to overcome that?

Comment: In order to create a shared pointer to an A object, you must know how to destroy an A object. In order to destroy an A object, you must be able to destroy a B object. And in order to destroy a B object, you must see the definition of B.

Comment: Ok, so in c++ you cannot call `delete` in a incomplete type.

Comment: @FelipeLavratti so you can't do anything like that with statically typed languages in general.

Answer (score 0):

The same reason `delete` does not work with incomplete types, `shared_ptr` does not too.

The solution is to provide a custom allocator function:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
  class B;
  std::unique_ptr<B> b;
  A();
};
std::shared_ptr<A> AMakeShared();

void foo() {
  AMakeShared();
}
```

The definition of the function `AMakeShared` must be in a translation unit where the  definition of `A::B` is not incomplete. Suppose another file.cpp containing:

```
class A::B {
}

std::shared_ptr<A> AMakeShared() {
    return std::make_shared<A>();
}
```